# String expression matcher using java

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

im looking for a the best method of extracting three strings from a big string.

my string is the following

```
x= " some test....  some text (some text, equipmentName: 'XXX', equipmentNumber: 'yyy', equipmentSlot: ‘zzz’) some text"
```

I want to extract three strings.

```
String1 = "equipmentName: 'XXX'"
String2= "equipmentNumber: 'yyy'"
String3 = "equipmentSlot: ‘zzz’"
```

should i use patteren matcher or just plain old java index of and last index of etc...

kindest regards.

Comment: Why the last single commas are not the same ? It is normal ?

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract strings using regex.

Try this:

```
String x = " some test....  some text (some text, equipmentName: 'XXX', equipmentNumber: 'yyy', equipmentSlot: ‘zzz’) some text";

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(equipment\\w+: ['|‘]\\w+['|’])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);

while(matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group());
}

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
equipmentName: 'XXX'
equipmentNumber: 'yyy'
equipmentSlot: ‘zzz’
```

About regex:

- `(...)` : Capture group
- `equipment\\w+` : Find parts starting with `"equipment"`
- `['|‘]` : To catch both `'...'` and `‘...’` parts
- `\\w` : Word character
- `+` : One or more times

Comment: @khalidalhussein glad to help. You should consider accepting/upvoting one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `regex` like `(equipment\w+: (?:['’‘]\w+['‘’]))` that will match the 3 elements

- `equipment\w+` for the different names
- `(?:['’‘]\w+['‘’])` comma around a word, in a non-capture group

Gives `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(equipment\\w+: (?:['’‘]\\w+['‘’]))");`

---

1. With classic looping on the result :

   ```
   Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
   List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
   while (m.find()) {
       res.add(m.group());
   }

   //[equipmentName: 'XXX', equipmentNumber: 'yyy', equipmentSlot: ‘zzz’]
   System.out.println(res);
   ```
2. With `Stream` interface

   ```
   List<String> res = p.matcher(x).results().map(MatchResult::group)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

   //[equipmentName: 'XXX', equipmentNumber: 'yyy', equipmentSlot: ‘zzz’]
   System.out.println(res);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
String input = " some test....  some text (some text, equipmentName: 'XXX', equipmentNumber: 'yyy', equipmentSlot: `zzz`) some text";
String pattern = "\\b(?:equipment(?:Name|Number|Slot)):\\s+['`].*?['`]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

This prints:

```
equipmentName: 'XXX'
equipmentNumber: 'yyy'
equipmentSlot: `zzz`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    String text = " some test....  some text (some text, equipmentName: 'XXX', equipmentNumber: 'yyy', equipmentSlot: 'zzz') some text";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("equipment[A-Za-z:]+ [A-Za-z'’‘]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

The output:

```
equipmentName: 'XXX'
equipmentNumber: 'yyy'
equipmentSlot: ‘zzz’
```